A no-rush iPhone document scanning app from multiple angles
Similar to iOS document scanning and stitching from multiple images. Is there an app which produces the best straightened scanned image of an A4 letter using its views from multi angles?
The built-in Scan Document functionality in Files app on iPhone doesn't "curate" much if the angle was off when picture of the document was taken. Moreover, it uses a single picture to produce the result in a very rushed manner; doesn't give us a chance to adjust or give any "guidance" whatsoever when the camera is pointed at the document, live.
